# Why is a PHP class method called on instantiation?

Tags: php, class

Need some help understanding what's going on in my PHP code.

**index.php**

```
include("cache.php");
$cache = new Cache();
```

**cache.php**

```
class Cache {
    private static $URL_CACHE;

    public function cache($url, $entityId) {
        echo '<br>caching '.$url.' as '.$entityId;
    }
```

When I request index.php, I get 'caching as' displayed, which is a surprise. I never called `$cache->cache('', '');`

What's calling the method?

---

As per Blake's answer, since the method name matches (somewhat) the class name, it's called on instantiation. For Java developers this will certainly be a  surprise.

Comment: This is using deprecated PHP functionality to act as a `__contruct()` method. In older versions of PHP (Removed in 7) If you had a class named `Foo` and a function named `foo()` it was how you would call it as a constructor. In short, this is being called by you instantiating the class. If you change your `cache()` method to `makeCache()` I bet it will go away.

Comment: @Blake you can put it as an aswer)

Comment: Right. Changed the method name and it works. Please do use your response as the answer, so others don't spend time chasing this.

Comment: Updated with answer. Feel free to mark is as the answer for future references @jacekn. Also, whoever downvoted - This is a perfectly valid question as to "Why is this happening?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using deprecated PHP functionality to act as a `__contruct()` method. In older versions of PHP (Removed in 7) If you had a class named `Foo` and a function named `foo()` it was how you would call it as a constructor.

In short, this is being called by you instantiating the class. If you change your `cache()` method to `makeCache()` I bet it will go away.

Another solution is to have an empty constructor as well, thanks JimL.

```
public function __construct() {

}
```

Comment: It's also an option to add an actual constructor method, which will avoid the PHP4 constructor functionality as well.